# Serverless nodejs mysql handshake error after deploy

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-serverless

I am working on serverless node basic application which has the basic function of CRUD operation with mysql. The mysql is created in the RDS Mysql and assigned to the public, In local system its connected and working fine, After the deploying serverless deploy, I am getting an error as **Handshake inactivity timeout** in response body.
Note: I used the serverless deploy and RDS MySQL in same AWS account.

Answer (score 0):

Even if both are deployed in the same account, and the RDS is public, the lambda might be deployed in a private subnet that does not have internet access. Without seeing your serverless deployment script, my guess is you may have to configure the correct security groups and subnets for your lambda function to be able to connect to this public database.

Here's a [medium article](https://medium.com/@antonio.cm.oliveira/how-to-access-your-rds-database-with-lambda-function-and-serverless-b7712dde9f80) that may help with the setup. Under the `vpc` configuration of your lambda function, you may have to modify the following.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  stage: prod
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  region: us-east-1
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - HERE_YOUR_SECURITY_GROUP 
    subnetIds:
      - HERE_YOUR_SUBNET_1
      - HERE_YOUR_SUBNET_2
      - HERE_YOUR_SUBNET_3
  environment:
    MYSQLHOST: 'xxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com'
    MYSQLPORT: 'xxx'
    MYSQLUSER: 'xxx'
    MYSQLPASS: 'xxxxx'
    MYSQLDATABASE: 'xxxx'
```